# С Новым 2022 Годом!

Tags: обсуждение, вехи, итоги-года

#### Год в цифрах

| Stack Overflow на русском | 2020 год | 2021 год |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Задано вопросов | 89 750 | 80 828 |
| Опубликовано ответов | 68 197 | 53 307 |
| Новых участников | 54 550 | 52 511 |

<sup>* Это абсолютные цифры, включая удаленные сообщения.</sup>

#### Несколько мыслей о будущем

В этом году [Stack Overflow (компания) стал частью Prosus](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/02/prosus-acquires-stack-overflow/). После завершения юридических процессов мы начали нанимать еще активнее. Сегодня команда управления сообществами состоит из 13 человек и, скорее всего, [станет еще больше в ближайшее время](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here/3726372/staff-community-manager-collectives). Аналогичные изменения происходит с командой разработки сайта. На мой взгляд, это позволит нам реализовать много полезных инициатив, о которых мы вместе много говорили ранее и создать еще больше инструментов для модерации сообщества и содержимого сайтов.

С оптимизмом и нетерпением жду наступления Нового Года! =)

#### Давайте поздравим друг друга!

Давайте закончим этот год и начнем следующий позитивно! Пожалуйста, присоединяйтесь к поздравлениям!  Поделитесь наиболее приятными позитивными событиями из жизни сообщества, которые запомнились вам больше всего. Если в уходящем году кто–то из участников сделал вашу жизнь лучше, пожалуйста, расскажите об этом в ответе к этому вопросу. Уверен, другие участники будут очень рад вашему вниманию.

Пусть 2022 год принесет счастье каждому из нас и всем нам одновременно :)

Comment: Пусть у нас с вами в Новом году на Stack Overflow всё будет, и ничего за это от модераторов не будет. Как-то так, и никак иначе. С Новым годом, друзья, коллеги!

Comment: Интересно, что число вопросов просело на 9.94%, а вот ответов — на 21.8%. ruSO стали покидать отвечающие? Или вопросы стали такие, что на них и отвечать не хочется?...

Comment: @Harry не, просто отвечающих побанили. Здесь же кто первый флаг воткнул, тот и прав. Я был и с той и с другой стороны. Это вполне систематические явления, не разовые, но сообщество повлиять ни на что не может, [посты на мете бесполезны](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb). Поэтому и желания отвечать примерно никакого. В этом году наверняка еще и комменты побанят тем, кто пытается в них отвечать, правила же.

Comment: @Harry Это очень интересный и сложный вопрос. По совпадению смотрел на количество вопросов и ответов на SOen пару месяцев назад и я вижу, что там происходят аналогичные процессы. На мой личный взгляд, дело скорее в людях, чем в вопросах. У нас всех время от время появляются жизненные обстоятельства, которые влияют на наши привычки, в том числе посещение сайтов. Это нормальный процесс. Проблема возникает, если не появляются новые участники, которые хотели бы двигать сообщество вперед.

Comment: Мне кажется, что один из важных факторов — зрелость SO. Это выражается, например, в большом количестве правил, сложности интерфейса, размере сообщества и т.д. Вероятно, ответ лежит в упрощении текущей системы как таковой и создании подсообществ в каком-либо виде. Подскажите, что думаете? Что по вашему мнению лежит в основе происходящих процессов?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, думаю, да, создание подсообществ и разделение тем по уровням (beginner, advanced, expert) с раздельной модерацией могло бы улучшить ситуацию (повысить активность и сплоченность внутри групп). Кстати, вы наверняка обратили внимание, что активность в данном топике разительно меньше, чем в таких же топиках за прошлые годы

Comment: @avp люди с подобных сайтов уходят после нескольких лет. В своё время так с форумов поуходили. Это естественный процесс.

Comment: @Harry или просто база постепенно наполняется. В перспективе весь сайт в ридонли режим перейдёт и будет как архив использоваться 

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, да, *"потеря смысла жизни в этих местах"* (это почти цитата из фильма Парфенова "Цвет нации") характерна для болота

Answer (score 11):

### Присоединяюсь к поздравлениям)

Будем надеяться, что в новом 2022 году будет больше новых участников, чем в 2021 :)

В этот год мне ясно запомнились @Zhihar, @GrAnd, @Insolor. Выражаю благодарность этим участникам. Спасибо за то, что делаете жизнь ruSO лучше!